# SSIS - Delay in loading data from Oracle DB to SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, oracle, performance, ssis, delay

We have a SSIS package which is loading data from Oracle DB table to SQL Server table the data is very huge so whenever the job is running its taking long time to insert the records. Below are the scenarios for our requirement,

There is no last modified column in source table so we cannot able to find which record updated and which one is newly inserted. Hence we are truncating destination table every time and load all the data from source table every time.

We have tried lookup transformation but no luck.

So can anyone please help me for better solution to create a correct package by loading data with less time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Oops. I assumed SQL server was referenced, so I changed to that.

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information here to even begin to help you. Basic performance tuning of your databases, tuning of the SQL statements involved, and possibly even tuning of the operating systems on each server would be needed. A thorough understanding of your server infrastructure and database architecture would be required to understand where the bottlenecks are and how to ease them (assuming it is even possible). In general you should be researching where the database or OS is spending its time - find the resource bottlenecks - and then alleviate them one by one.

Comment: If you have no way of telling what is "new" data, and what isn't, then neither of the SQL hosts are going to either. Perhaps you should be looking at adding a "modified date time" column to the data, so that you can get the "oldest" date from your destination table, and then filter to data that is greater than that value.

Comment: I was once presented this exact situation.  Source data was just under 1 million rows, copied in full.  It was taking in excess of 4 hours to complete when it was brought to me.  I put a 10046 trace on the operation and found that SSIS was doing a row-by-row, slow-by-slow operation - each row being a separate IO, network transmission, ack, etc.  Once I saw that, it took me less than 30 minutes to write a PL/SQL procedure to do a simple INSERT INTO .. (SELECT ... FROM ..., and that executed in about 4 minutes.  I've had zero faith in SSIS ever since.